# Moving WPF Controls at Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF window that is completely transparent with no title bar that contains a few buttons. How can I drag just the controls around?

Comment: Look at drag and drop and put the controls on a canvas.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx  And don't use the term form in WFP.

Comment: You want to drag window or just each control separately?

Comment: I want to drag all the controls on the window together, but I do not want to drag the window -- only the controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the DragCanvas.cs from [here](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid5A7DD8E08F73F34D499A661BBB35612D677874A1.aspx?s=%22Josh%20Smith%22#L1)
its inherited from `Canvas` control give it a transparent background, and it'll do the job for you.

You can also add a DragCanvas as child to another DragCanvas and move many controls at the same time

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

    <local:DragCanvas Background="Green">
        <Grid Canvas.Left="48" Canvas.Top="57">
            <Image Source="cursor_drag_arrow.png" Margin="233,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="33" Width="29"></Image>
        <Button Content="Button" x:Name="btn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Margin="110,77,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124"/>
            <Button Content="Button" x:Name="btn_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124"/>
        </Grid>
    </local:DragCanvas>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

there is no code behind this just click on the image and drag

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on how this control works? Does it drag by clicking down on the canvas and moving the mouse around? I neglected to add this part in the question, but I'm looking for a small button-like control that can be held down to drag all of the controls around simultaneously. The controls can be placed in another container for convenience, but I do want to retain my click-through when anything except a button is clicked. Thanks.

Comment: yes, sure it does, just make a transparent container with a small image background where you drag from

Comment: Ok, I'm looking through the documentation right now and I'll give it a try when I get back home.

Comment: the file is 403 @S3ddi9