# Click and drag over buttons in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, click, drag

I have many buttons on my page. Every button has his own Click implementation.

When I click on some button and move the mouse to another button under that click (like drag), I want that click will fire on last button.

I have triend to do it with `DragEnter` and `DragOver` events but nothing happens.

```
<Button Click="btn1_click" DragOver="btn1_click"/>
```

Comment: Dont know if I understanded you correctly, but try with `MouseLeftButtonUp` or `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` events.

Comment: @Kirenenko, yes, i also have tried this events, but they didn't fired. Maybe something prevent it, but simple Click works good

Comment: use Window_MouseMove event and then check if mouse is over the  buttons like this :  `if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed  && (btn1.IsMouseOver || btn2.IsMouseOver) { ....} `

Comment: You may wanna look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632317/wpf-drag-and-drop-on-a-button